# How to make items show under tabs?

Tags: javascript, tabs

foreach function is not working in this code. I need to show items under tabs, How to do that. Items come from a cms and I need to show them in a tab pannel. This is the code I wrote

```
export default function () {
 const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
 const items = document.querySelectorAll('.guides-block__item');

 function showActiveTabItems() {
   const activeTab = document.querySelector('.tab.active');
   const activeTabItems = document.querySelectorAll(`.guides-block__item[data- 
   tab="${activeTab.dataset.tab}"]`);

   items.forEach(item => {
     if (activeTabItems.includes(item)) {
       item.style.display = 'block';
     } else {
       item.style.display = 'none';
     }
   });
}

 for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
   tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
   tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
  tab.classList.remove('active');
});
this.classList.add('active');
showActiveTabItems();
});
}
 showActiveTabItems();
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr? I don't get the problem